# Earliest European novel that was set during an epidemic

Tags: history-of-literature

Wikipedia's [list of epidemics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_epidemics) shows that epidemics have plagued us for almost as long as recorded history.
Some great works of literature describe events caused or triggered by an epidemic, for example:

- in the play [*Oedipus Rex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus_Rex), the plague is ravaging Thebes,
- in Giovanni Boccaccio's [*Decameron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decameron), a number of young people flee to the countryside while the plague rages in Florence and tell each other stories to while away the time,
- Daniel Defoe's novel [*A Journal of the Plague Year*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Journal_of_the_Plague_Year) (1722) is based on the bubonic plague that struck London in 1665-1666,
- Jean Giono's novel [*Le Hussard sur le toit* / *The Horseman on the Roof*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Horseman_on_the_Roof_(novel)) (1951) describes events set during a cholera epidemic, and
- perhaps most famously, Albert Camus' novel [*La Peste* / *The Plague*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plague) (1947) describes the effects of the plague in the French Algerian city of Oran.

The oldest novel in the above list is Daniel Defoe's *A Journal of the Plague Year* (1722), since *The Decameron* is not a novel but a collection of short stories tied together by a frame story.
However, what was the oldest European novel that was set during an epidemic? Note that it is not sufficient that a novel merely mentions the epidemic; the epidemic needs to determine the main character's action for at least 50% of the story. It does not matter whether the epidemic is to be taken literally (see Boccaccio and Defoe) or whether it symbolizes something else (Giono).

Comment: Relevant reading, not an answer: [Epidemics in Literature](http://workshyfop.blogspot.com/2014/05/epidemics-in-literature.html); [Pandemics ... from literary history](http://theconversation.com/pandemics-from-homer-to-stephen-king-what-we-can-learn-from-literary-history-133572) (citing [an analysis](https://ca.ucpress.edu/content/6/1/1) of plague as a stage-setter for the *Iliad*, also Shelley's *The Last Man*); [Writing the Present, Rewriting the Plague](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/ciberletras/v07/vieira.html); [a review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20616433?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: And more academic articles: [Pandemic Fear and Literature](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4193163/) (good literature review at the start), [Plague Writing](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/004724418101104202) (I can't access the full text of this one), [Contagious Horror](http://www.clinmedres.org/content/17/1-2/41.long). Nobody mentions any novels older than Defoe's.